# When making prediction with a trained neural net, does input have to run through all layers?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, predict, inference

When you have an input that you want to make a prediction on, does the input have to be run through the entire neural net?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how current neural networks work. The only exception are some state of the art networks such as [CNNs with Adaptive Inference Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11503).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In most Neural Nets, each layer except the final one will generally produce outputs that do not correspond to output categories. Instead, these intermediate layers extract features and find patterns in the output from the previous layer. Only the final layer looks at all these high-level features (produced by the combination of all previous layers) to decide how the input should be categorised ([example](http://www.amax.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/blog_deeplearning3.jpg)).